# How can I run a Spring Boot program against an AWS SQS instance from a Ubuntu VM?

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

I have a Spring Boot application that I am trying to run against an SQS queue from an Ubuntu VM. I've set up the Application.java to create a QueueMessagingTemplate from an AmazonSQSClient which, in turn, is made of BasicAWSCredentials read from a credentials file. I have also created a credentials file with my access keys at "~/.aws/credentials". However, Spring Boot is failing with the error message:

```
ERROR 9858 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application startup failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'simpleMessageListenerContainer'; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

Here is what my Application.java looks like:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.config.annotation.EnableContextCredentials;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.config.annotation.EnableContextRegion;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableContextCredentials(accessKey = "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}", secretKey = "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}")
@EnableContextRegion(region = "${AWS_REGION}")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        return mapper;
    }

    public BasicAWSCredentials credentialsProvider(String accessKey, String secretKey) {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentialsProvider = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        return awsCredentialsProvider;
    }

    public AmazonSQSClient sqs(String accessKey, String secretKey){
        return new AmazonSQSClient(credentialsProvider(accessKey, secretKey));
    } 

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueTemplate(
    @Value("${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}") String accessKey,
            @Value("${AWS_SECRET_KEY}") String secretKey) {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(sqs(accessKey, secretKey));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all references to AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY in the code to see if it will use the `~/.aws/credentials` file?